# MATLAB: vectorized indexing confused with vector*matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing, vectorization

I have a calculation that I want to perform element by element.

```
foreach i from i=1 to i=N
    RES_i = det(A - V_i * I) // notice V_i and RES_i are SCALARS
```

where for example A is 3x3 , I is 3x3, V and RES are 1xN.

so basically what I do is

```
idx=1:81
res(idx) = det( A - V(idx)*I );
```

BUT, this get interperted as taking the whole of V and multiplying by I.

this seems like a simple example but I can't figure out how to vectorize it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this isn't Matlab code...

Second: I think you confuse "vectorization" with an implicit loop. Vectorization means to apply an operation to a whole arrays at once, using vector/matrix/tensor notation and operations. What you want is however an implicit for-each type loop, and it makes total sense that Matlab complains about it.

There's no other way than to write it out explicitly:

```
res = zeros(81,1);
for ii = 1:numel(res)
    res(ii) = det(A-V(ii)*I);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You perform element-by-element operation by using . together with the operator of choice.  For example:

```
Element-by-element multiplication: .* 
Element-by-element division: ./
```

and so on... is that what you mean?